# Horizontal ul navigation aligned to the right side

Tags: html, css, navigation, html-lists

i'm trying to create a horizontal navigation which is aligned to the right side of the parent element. You can see the navigation at http://kaffeeprinzen.jag-aelskar.de/ where it says "Espresso".

My HTML is:

```
<ul id="menu-standard">
    <li id="menu-item"><a>Item 4</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item"><a>Item 3</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item"><a>Item 2</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item"><a>Item 1</a></li>
</ul>
```

My CSS is:

```
.menu li { 
    float: right;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

It works like this, the only problem is that the order in the list is wrong. The first item is the last one in the html code.

Any tips for me? Thanks a lot!
Yannis

Answer (score 23):

Try floating the `ul` right rather than each `li`. Each `li` can float left.

```
#menu-standard { 
    float: right;
}

#menu-standard li { 
    float: left;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/HsUTQ/

---

`float: right` will float the items, in order, to the right. Meaning the 1st element will be the right-most, then 2nd element the next-right-most, etc.

Comment: Hi, thanks but thats exactly my problem. I can use float:left; but then it gets aligned to the left side - not to the right and doesn't fit my design anymore...

Comment: I had a typo on my jsfiddle, see my update, it's all floating as you'd like.

Comment: You are my hero. thanks a lot! it works perfectly! Have a nice day!